# How is pandas converting my data into categories in this line of code?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I need help understanding this line of code:

```py
y_train2 = train_target2.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Am I right in saying that `y_train2` is being changed to a categorical variable using `astype(category)` and then `cat.codes` is used to change it into integers?

Below is the full block of code.

```py
# Train data pre-processing
train_target2 = df_train_01['class_2'] 
train_target5 = df_train_01['class_5']

df_train_02.drop(['class_2', 'class_5'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# convert text labels to integers
y_train2 = train_target2.astype('category').cat.codes
y_train5 = train_target5.astype('category').cat.codes

# Test data pre-processing
test_target2 = df_test_01['class_2'] 
test_target5 = df_test_01['class_5']

# drop 'class_2' and 'class_5' columns
df_test_02.drop(['class_2', 'class_5'], axis=1, inplace=True)
y_test2 = test_target2.astype('category').cat.codes
y_test5 = test_target5.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: Please be specific about what you don't understand.  Track the wording form the documentation, referring to the values you printed before and after the conversion.  Include the information in your question, and remove the superfluous code -- keep only enough to support the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: I thought I explained it in the question ? the single  line of code at the top Is what I do not understand, the block of code under it is the rest of it

Comment: I agree with rcon313; he/she made it clear what was the question and what is it that wants to be explained. Prune's comment is unfair and even meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding on the dataframe function and attribute is correct; pdf.astype('category') is turning values into categorical data and pdf.Categorical.codes() (or pdf.Series.codes() ) is an attribute  that converts the values into a set of integers that start with 0.
Try to type some simple snippet below to see how they work.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
pdf = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=['s-length', 's-width', 'p-length', 'p-width'])

print(
  iris['s-length'].astype('category'),
  len(np.unique(iris['s-length'])), # -> 35
  len( set(iris['s-length'].astype('category').cat.codes ), # -> 35
  np.unique(iris['s-length'].astype('category').cat.codes)), # -> array([ 0, 1,...34]), dtype=int8)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, a pandas categorical data type is a mapping between values that do not have a numeric interpretation and a unique number for each value.

Let's break down your code:

```py
# Take the series `train_target2` and convert it to categorical type
train_target2.astype('category')

# Access the attributes or methods of a categorical series
train_target2.astype('category').cat

# Take the `codes` attribute
train_target2.astype('category').cat.codes
```

In reality, `.codes` is not converting the data into numbers. Rather, you are only taking the numeric equivalent of each category. Strictly speaking, `.astype('category')` is the part that converted your data to categorical.

You can find the attributes and methods of this data type [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#Attributes).